# Repositioning images

Tags: image

We've uploaded a bunch of images into EE but when they're added into templated image sections, many of them are too high or too low. Is it possible to reposition these images in EE without having to fix them and then re-upload into EE?

Comment: Do you mean that the images are of the wrong size? This sounds to me like a layout issue with your templates and/or CSS.

Comment: so they're a little larger than they need to be i guess. rather than cropping the image and re-uploading, was looking for a way to just drag the image up or down so the main section shows in the image holder.

Answer (score 2):

You could crop them in the template to make them the correct size / aspect ratio.

Here's a free addon for that: https://github.com/bjornbjorn/img.ee_addon